# Node.js with parse.com (ParseOpenSource javascript sdk) installed - fails on AWS eb deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to 'eb deploy' a node.js with javascript sdk addition.

It works fine locally but every time I have tried to - eb deploy- it I get this in the logs

```
    npm ERR!     npm bugs node-express
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-express
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

> node-express@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node main.js

{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'parse/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/api/common/parse.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
...npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-express@0.0.0 start: `node main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-express@0.0.0 start script 'node main.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-express package,
```

I have repeatedly tried 
npm install express --save
and yes I have also run npm install parse (it all works fine locally).

To no avail.  Why would it all work like a charm locally but not on AWS EB ?

-Thanks for any clues.

Comment: Parse.com has shut down their service, so I'd imagine that might cause you some difficulty.

Comment: @Adam sorry for the confusion. I am using the Open Source Parse.com Platform.  Not sure what to call it these days ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help someone.  Ultimately I solved this by

'npm install moduleName --save' on all of my modules. One by one.

Still not sure why the site worked locally ? 
-best of luck.